# T-SQL 2012, While Loop maximum iterations?

Tags: t-sql, crash, while-loop, sql-server-2012, max

I encountered something in SQL 2012 with a WHILE loop in T-SQL that I haven't seen before, and wouldn't expect. After troubleshooting, it appears I am correct, but wanted to confirm whether anyone else has run across this, or if they can duplicate it.

A WHILE loop appears to have a maximum iteration count of a little more than 13 million iterations.  I will provide the two samples of code below, one that broke, and the other that worked around this limitation.  (If you want to know why I'm doing it, I'd like to build a "data warehouse" with semi-random selections of data that can later be used for testing, and this seems like the easiest path to create that.  So these code samples are simply tests to ensure I'll be able to do that.)

```
    DATABASE: TESTDB
    TABLE: tbl_A
    COLUMNS:
        a (PK, bigint, not null) --Starts at zero, count upward
        b (bigint, not null) -- Starts at 1 Quadrilion, count downward
        c (bitint, null) -- empty for now
```

Then I insert one record:

```
    INSERT INTO tbl_A (a, b) VALUES (0, 999999999999999);
```

Then I run the following, which causes VS 2012 to hang and crash after a little more than 13 million iterations in the while loop:

```
USE TESTDB
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;
---------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @countUp bigint = (SELECT max(a)+1 FROM [dbo].[tbl_A]);
DECLARE @countDown bigint = (SELECT min(b)-1 FROM [dbo].[tbl_A]);
---------------------------------------------------------------------
WHILE (@countDown > 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_A (a, b) VALUES (@countUp, @countDown);
    SET @countUp += 1;
    SET @countDown -= 1;

    IF ((@countDown % 1000000) = 0)
        PRINT char(9) + char(9) + char(9) + char(9) + CAST(@loop AS VARCHAR) + ': ' + CAST(@countDown AS VARCHAR) + '  <--- (' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 120) + ')';
    ELSE IF ((@countDown % 200000) = 0)
        PRINT CAST(@loop AS VARCHAR) + ': ' + CAST(@countDown AS VARCHAR);
END
---------------------------------------------------------------------
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

HOWEVER, when I force the above code to stop the WHILE loop at 13 million, so it never gets to the point of hanging, and then create a WHILE loop around that one, while @countDown > 0, it seems to continue running fine well beyond 13+ million transactions in the DB...it's still running now at nearly 26 million...and still going...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
---------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @loop int = 1;
DECLARE @countUp bigint = (SELECT max(a)+1 FROM [dbo].[tbl_A]);
DECLARE @countDown bigint = (SELECT min(b)-1 FROM [dbo].[tbl_A]);
DECLARE @StopValue bigint;
    IF (@countDown > 13000000)
        SET @StopValue = @countDown - 13000000;
    ELSE
        SET @StopValue = 0;

WHILE (@countDown > 0)
BEGIN
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        WHILE (@countDown <> @StopValue)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_A (a, b) VALUES (@countUp, @countDown);
            SET @countUp += 1;
            SET @countDown -= 1;

            IF ((@countDown % 1000000) = 0)
                PRINT char(9) + char(9) + char(9) + char(9) + CAST(@loop AS VARCHAR) + ': ' + CAST(@countDown AS VARCHAR) + '  <--- (' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 120) + ')';
            ELSE IF ((@countDown % 200000) = 0)
                PRINT CAST(@loop AS VARCHAR) + ': ' + CAST(@countDown AS VARCHAR);
        END
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        SET @loop += 1;
        SELECT @countUp=(max(a)+1) FROM [dbo].[tbl_A];
        SELECT @countDown=(min(b)-1) FROM [dbo].[tbl_A];
        IF (@countDown > 13000000)
            SET @StopValue = @countDown - 13000000;
        ELSE
            SET @StopValue = 0;
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

---

Has anyone else ever encountered this?  Or, are you able to duplicate it?  I'm wondering if it's some setting in my VS 2012, a general max setting MS puts on the WHILE loop, or something specific to my system...

Seems like my system also has sufficient disk space and power.  So I doubt that would have any impact on this limitation.

```
    Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit
    SQL Server 2012 Dev. Ed. 64bit
    6-core 3.47 GHz (12-way with hyper threading)
    24 GB DDR3-1600 Memory
    OS on SSD (3 Gbps SATA II)
    DB is on two SSD drives in RAID 0 config (on 6 Gbps SATA III)
```

Curious for feedback.  (Sorry for such a long post.)

Answer (score 2):

If our loop condition is a "number equal to or greater then number", then, having the [T-SQL number types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) we can choose, *BIGINT* type for our test.

Because the following statements:

```
DECLARE @LoopLimit  BIGINT = 9223372036854775807
SET @LoopLimit = @LoopLimit + 1 
GO

DECLARE @LoopLimit  BIGINT = -9223372036854775808
SET @LoopLimit = @LoopLimit - 1
GO
```

generates:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 3 Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting expression to data type bigint.

I guess the biggest iteration cycle is something like the follow:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @LoopLimit  BIGINT = 9223372036854775807

    WHILE @LoopLimit <> -9223372036854775808
    BEGIN
        SET @LoopLimit = @LoopLimit - 1
    END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Unfortunately, I am at work and I am not able to wait for the whole query to be executed ( I might be run it at home before going to bed), but I have the the following query to check if 13 millions iterations are passed:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @LoopLimit  BIGINT = 9223372036854775807
    DECLARE @MilionsCounter BIGINT = 0

    WHILE @LoopLimit <> -9223372036854775808
    BEGIN
        SET @LoopLimit = @LoopLimit - 1
        SET @MilionsCounter = @MilionsCounter + 1
        IF @MilionsCounter % 1000000 = 0 PRINT @MilionsCounter / 1000000
    END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

[image]

So, it is still running. You can check it yourself that there is no limitations of 13 millions (tested on SQL Management Studio 2012).